# Возможен ли lazy loading при связи один к одному

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

[Здесь](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.6.php) показана связь один к одному, но здесь используется подход eager loading. Попробовал использовать lazy loading. но он не работает. А у меня есть сущность `Team`, он связан с сущность `Player` связью один ко многим, а вот между сущностями `Player` и `Coach` связь один к одному. Мне надо получить значения свойства `Name` сущности `Coach` через сущность Team, т.е.:

```
    using (TeamContext db = new TeamContext())
    {
       foreach (Team t in db.Teams)
       {
           foreach(Player p in t.Players)
               Console.WriteLine(p.Coach.Name); //NullReferenceException
       }
    }
```

Модели:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Coach Coach { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Coach
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Player")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}
```

Контекст:

```
class TeamContext : DbContext
{
    public string Bovaria { get; private set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coach> Coachs { get; set; }
}
```

Строка подключения:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TeamContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Teamstest;Integrated Security=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Метод Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TeamContext db = new TeamContext())
        {
           foreach (Team t in db.Teams)
           {
               foreach(Player p in t.Players)
                   Console.WriteLine(p.Coach.Name); //NullReferenceException
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Как подгрузить тренера, для всех игроков в команде?

Comment: Ленивая загрузка подразумевает что свойство будет virtual

Comment: У вас какая то избыточная связь между таблицами.

Comment: Тренер тренирует лишь одного игрока? Одумайтесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что бы воспользоваться *ленивой загрузкой* Вам необходимо что бы это свойство было **virtual** т.е. что то типа `public virtual Coach Coach {get;set;}`;

и как Вам уже написал @PavelMayorov пересмотрите структуру бд, тренер не у игрока а у команды, если же Вы хотите иметь возможность получить тренера для игрока то я бы попробовал как то так:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CoachId {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoachId")]    
    public virtual Coach Coach { get;set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeamId")]
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Coach
{
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

тогда получить тренера для игрока можно как то так

```
var player = db.Players.First();
var playerCoach = player.Team.Coach;
```

т.е. в данном случае мы воспользовались *навигационными полями* для получения тренера для конкретного игрока